# Xpath query not returning all children?

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I am attempting to parse data from a remote web page.  I retrieve it using curl and then use loadHTML() to create a DOMDocument().

I run into the problem of wanting to select by classname and tried several solutions but the most accepted method seems to be to use an xpath query which I do as:

```
$classname = 'content-container-primary character-list';
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$results = $xpath->query("//*[@class='" . $classname . "']");
```

This finds the container on line 134 of the pastebin linked text which resembles (abbreviated for clarity):

```
<div class="content-container-primary character-list">
    <ul class="list-group media-list media-list-stream m-t-0">
        <li class="list-group-item p-a">
            <span class="header-buttons"></span>
            <span class="header-text"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item p-a visible-xs">
            <div class="row sw-ad-mrec mobile"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="media list-group-item p-a collection-char-list">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I could search for the UL using `$classname = 'list-group media-list media-list-stream m-t-0';` directly, but I'm concerned that since they're using classnames and not  IDs that the UL class name seems less specific and might be reused elsewhere.  Finding this UL as a child of the DIV with class 'character-list' gives me some confidence I'm looking at the right object.

What I want to find is all of the "col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" class items.  I'm not sure how this name is programmatically generated and I don't want to rely on it, so no xpath search for that, instead I thought to treat these as children of the `<li class="media list-group-item p-a collection-char-list">` container which itself is a child of the searched for `<ul class="list-group media-list media-list-stream m-t-0">` container is a child of my $results->item(0) ... so far so good, if I then check the object I find the UL child has been correctly found.  Once found I copy it into a temporary DOMDocument so I can do more xpath searching.

```
$temp_dom = new DOMDocument();
foreach($results->item(0)->childNodes as $n) {
    if ( $n->nodeType === 1 ) {
        if( $n->getAttribute("class") == 'list-group media-list media-list-stream m-t-0' );
            $temp_dom->appendChild($temp_dom->importNode($n,true));
        }
    }
}
```

So far so good.  Now I have confidence I have the UL I want, but when I attempt:

```
$classname = 'media list-group-item p-a collection-char-list';
$xpathUL = new DOMXPath( $temp_dom );
$result2 = $xpathUL->query("//*[@class='" . $classname . "']");
```

I get an empty result, DOMNodeList Object ( [length] => 0 ).

Investigating I attempted:

```
$nodes = array();
$nodes = $temp_dom->getElementsByTagName( 'li' );

foreach ( $nodes as $node ) {
    echo $node->getAttribute( "class" ).'<br>';
}
```

Which shows the first 2 LI objects but not the third.

If I go back to the original `$dom` object and perform the xpath search using the classname of the li that I'm interested in it does appear within the results.

I'm uncertain where I've got off track.  I know this solution feels pretty clunky but it performs well enough for my purposes.

Please note I have no control over the format of the remote page and have to work with the format as is.

Complete sample is available at [this pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/DsYweSVk).

Comment: *"What I want to find is all of the "col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" class items."* Have you tried this? `//*[@class='media list-group-item p-a collection-char-list']/*[@class='row']/*[@class='col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2']` I've noticed there's a div class row in middle but I'm not php guy so I can't test your code.

Comment: @derloopkat This extracts precisely what I'm looking for, thank you for sharing it.  I'm still not sure why my posted code does not work, but I will happily give you the big green checkmark if you move your comment into an answer.

Comment: glad to here that, moved to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've noticed there's a div class "row" in middle of the structure.

You could try a more advanced xpath query string:

```
//*[@class='media list-group-item p-a collection-char-list']/*[@class='row']/*[@class='col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2']
```